# How can you force focus to a React object after clicking on that object?

Tags: reactjs

I have React component which has an input element that is a child property of a GridItem component from https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/lib/GridItem.jsx

When I click into the input element for some reason the insertion point is not showing and I can't make any edits. I think the click is propagating through to the GridItem. I've tried to stop propagation but the issue remains.

Currently doing this

```
e.target.focus()
alert('Hello')
```

which works, the insertion point is correct and I can do edits,
whereas

```
e.target.focus()
```

fails, the insertion point is not shown and I'm unable to do edits.

My colleague suggested using jQuery but I'd like to avoid that.

How can you force focus to a React object after clicking on that object?

Comment: could you use a `ref` to manually invoke `focus()` after the event cycle - ie something like `this.cellRef.current.focus()`  ?

Comment: Possibly. I'll do some research.

Comment: Sure, this is a good place to start: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs - note the use case "managing focus", hope that helps